# Get the summarized data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have embedded a report in which I have display box that will show the summarized data of the visual whenever I click on any visual. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the summarized data of a selected visual by using `exportData` and `dataSelected` event, Please find the below code snippet:

1. Get the visual name by using `dataSelected` event:

```js
report.on("dataSelected", function (event) {
    const visualName = event.detail.visual.name;
});
```

2. Get the current active page:

```js
const pages = await report.getPages();

let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
    return page.isActive
})[0];
```

3. Get the required visual:

```js
const visuals = await page.getVisuals();

let visual = visuals.filter(function (visual) {
    return visual.name === visualName;
})[0];
```

4. Get the summarized data using `exportData`:

```js
const result = await visual.exportData(models.ExportDataType.Summarized);
```

Please find the references here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/export-data
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events#dataselected